# How can I make a field visible depending on the content of another field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, powerapp, if-condition

I have a PowerApp which is working really well so far, it is based on a SharePoint list which holds the data. There is a date field (Paid Date) which defaults to 31/12/2001 for some reason, and I want this hidden from view until there is a useful value in it because the default date is confusing people.

I want to make *Paid Date* visible depending on a field called *Stage* being set to 'Stage 7' but can't seem to work out how.

So: how do I set the visibility of a field based on the value entered in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **Visible** property of your **Paid Date** field based on the value of your field **Stage**.

To check the value of Stage is equal to "Stage 7" or not, you need to use **[IF function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if)**.

You need to use your formula in **Visible** property of Paid Date field something like below:

```
IF(Stage.Value = "Stage 7", true, false)
```

Also, another way is to use **Variable** in PowerApps and set its value `onStart` of your PowerApp to desired default value and then use the condition based on the variable value.

**Reference**:

[Make field visible depended on other field - Powerapps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Flow/Make-field-visible-depended-on-other-field-Powerapps/m-p/51876).

Comment: That link isn't working for me: This page isn’t working. techcommunity.microsoft.com didn’t send any data.

Comment: Oh I checked it. It was working before 5 minutes. I believe there is some issue with the site. You will be able to access it after some time. However, you can set **Visible** property of your Paid Date Data Card to achieve your requirement.

Comment: You can also found similar questions [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-PowerApps-Formerly/Conditional-visibility-question/td-p/142940) and [here](https://www.powerappsug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=d6dac367-b2b5-484b-84e1-e803f653b9f0&CommunityKey=9f5c6fd1-bb0c-4ffa-adab-06d3d72c11da&tab=digestviewer).

Comment: Thanks, it has fixed the issue. I would have accepted it even before the comment if I wasn't curious about the link.

Comment: Welcome, glad it worked for you.